# Android Gradle Build is taking extreamly long for no reason

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I build or sync gradle in Android studio it takes a very long time and I'm not really sure why it happens, I tried uninstalling and deleting all files then installing again and is still happening, it happens in all projects, I even reinstalled and started a new project with only the "hello world" text view and it took around 13 minutes to compile. 
[image]

[image]

I don't know if these images help, this is the build with the hello world project. if you need any other information, tell me where to look for it and ill post it PLEASE HELP.

**EDIT:**
I updated Android Studio and built again and I got the following information; these processes are taking the most time:

:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug 3 m 19 s 175 ms
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug 3 m 30 s 967 ms
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug **15 m 31 s 159 ms**
:app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug    1 m 6 s 762 ms

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of your internet connectivity. If you don't have good internet connectivity try enabling "Offline work" under android studio settings.

Build,Execution, Deployment ->Build Tools ->Gradle.

Comment: already tried that and is still SLOW!, still using only the hello world example

Answer (score 0):

You batter use offline gradle.

- Use local gradle destribution
- Check Offline work

[image]